# How to read only specific objects of a type from a collection with multiple object types

Tags: java, object, hashmap, set, hashset

I have a collection with two object types. I want to only read one of the two types into a new Set.
Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: you could wrap that map into another map `Map<String,Map<WhateverObject,WhateverObject>>` and seperate the objects by theyr actuall class.

Comment: You can use org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate class to handle in elegant way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Google Guava's filter.

```
Collections2.filter(yourOriginalCollection, new Predicate<Object>() {
    public boolean apply(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof TypeYouAreInterestedIn;
    }
});
```

Or in Java 8:

```
Collections2.filter(yourOriginalCollection, (obj) -> obj instanceof TypeYouAreInterestedIn);
```

Comment: No problem, I think these lambda expressions are such a cool feature which finally arrived to Java 8, so we have to spread the word :D

Answer (score 1):

Like Suresh said there is no built in functionality, here some sort of complete code:

```
for(Object obj : yourOldCollection) {
    if(obj instanceof SearchedType){
       yourNewSet.add(obj);
    }
}
```